# Training a Face Recognizer takes a lot of time

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

Training the Face Recognizer is taking a lot of time.

Is this time machine dependent?

Any tips for minimizing this time if I am having data for a few hundred people?

Comment: did you try the lbp face reco ? much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is machine dependent, depending on where you have the pictures I/O can be an issue as they have to read entirely.

I currently train ~ 5500 pictures a day on two different models (opencv models) and it takes ~ 40 minutes for one and three hours for another.  But there's probably about 15 minutes of pre-processing that I do before I even begin the training which includes:

Gray scaling everything
Cropping faces
Facial alignment
Verifying

I found that if you will be doing a lot of additions to your picture repository, its easier to save, load and if the model is updateable, update and re-save to avoid training again upon a instantiation.

Good luck,
Orlando